# Full battery notification in Ubuntu Script.sh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, notifications, battery

I have this script to get a notification when battery is over 80% but it doesn't work

The problem is something like:

`/home/aerolito/battery-full-notification/batteryfull.sh: line 7: [: 0 100: integer expression expected`

### Here the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    battery_percent=$(acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)')
    if on_ac_power; then
        if [ "$battery_percent" -gt 80 ]; then
              
            notify-send -i "$PWD/battery-full-notification/batteryfullR.png" "Battery full."  "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
            # notify-send -i "$PWD/batteryfullR.png" "Battery full." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
            paplay /usr/share/sounds/other/rings.ogg
        fi
    fi
    sleep 300 # (5 minutes)
done
```

Comment: acpi | grep | tail -n1

Comment: If I run `acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'` on my laptop, it returns 3 values.  An `if` requires 1 value only.  And it does require a value, it cannot be empty either.

Comment: what should I write? nic3500

Comment: [tail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) -n1